# Changing the y-axis text size with doubleYScale plot

Tags: r, lattice

I made a `doubleYScale` plot:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

# Some data
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

obj1 <- xyplot(y~ x, data=foo,xlab=list(cex=1.2), 
               main="TOtalProduktion VS SummaSkulder/TotaltKapital i procent",
               type = c("l","g"),col="black",
               lty=1,key = simpleKey(col=c('black'),
               text=c("Produktion"),cex=1.2,points=FALSE, lines=TRUE),
               scales=list(x=list(rot=90,tick.number=25,
               cex=1,axs="r")))

obj2 <- xyplot(y^2 ~ x,data= foo ,type = "o",col="black",
               lty=9,key = simpleKey(col=c('black'),
               text=c("Summa.skulder"),cex=1.2,lines=FALSE,points= TRUE))

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

[image]

The `problem` is that I cant manage to change the text size of the y-axic labels (`y` and `y^2` text, I want to make it larger). It is no problem to change it if I only plot `obj1` or `obj2` separately, but it doesn't work for `doubleYScale`...

I can on the other hand change the size of numbers on the y-axices with:

```
trellis.par.set(axis.text=list(cex=1))
```

Any suggestions? I can't manage to find a way :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    library(grid)
    ##  the text size of the 2 y-axic labels
    grid.edit(gPath='GRID.text',grep=T,global=T,gp =gpar(cex=3))
```

If you want to set different axis sizes

```
    grobs <- sapply(grid.get(gPath='GRID.text',grep=T,global=T),'[')['name',]
    grid.edit(gPath=grobs[[1]],gp =gpar(cex=2))
    grid.edit(gPath=grobs[[2]],gp =gpar(cex=1.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice one! Gonna accept your answer because I did not know grid solution!:) But is there a way with latticeExtra, do you know?

Comment: I added a solution below without using `grid`. I realize this question was asked more than two years ago, but it may be helpful for others looking for a solution...

Comment: @sparrow +1! but it is not more than 2 years ago (1 year and few months) :) Yes helpful but generally double axis is not recommended since it is not very readable.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution directly with `lattice` and `latticeExtra`:
 where you can set the size of all axis labels independently:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

obj1 <- xyplot(y~ x, data=foo,
               xlab=list("Thing", fontsize = 22),
               ylab = list("Something", fontsize = 32),
               ylab.right = list("Anything", fontsize = 16),
               par.settings = simpleTheme(col = 1),
               type = c("l","g"),
               lty=1,
               scales=list(x=list(rot=90,tick.number=25,
                                  cex=1,axs="r")))

obj2 <- xyplot(y^2 ~ x,data= foo ,type = "o",col="black",
               lty=9)

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2)
```

[image]

Comment: how to apply cex in  ylab2 ? in plot you showed 3 different size of labs, I need put cex=1.5 in ylab2.

Comment: you can just play with `fontsize` and specify it to according to your needs

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer your question, but mixing two plots of different size on one axis may not be the best approach as it can be misleading. Perhaps a faceted plot using `ggplot` would do the job as well or better? All the elements below are easily adjusted.

[image: faceted plot]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

set.seed(123)
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))

foo <- as.data.frame(foo)
foo$z <- foo$y^2
mymelt <- melt(foo, id.var = 'x')
mymelt$label <- ifelse(mymelt$variable == 'y', "Produktion", "Summa.skulder")
mymelt$line.colour <- ifelse(mymelt$variable == 'y', "red", "blue") # specify colours here

ggplot(data = mymelt, aes(x = x, y = value)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = mymelt$line.colour)) +
    facet_wrap(~ label, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
    scale_colour_manual(values = unique(mymelt$line.colour)) +
    ggtitle("TOtalProduktion VS SummaSkulder/TotaltKapital i procent") +
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9)) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9)) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15)) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + # comment out this line if you want an x axis title
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + # comment out this line if you want a y axis title
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: thanks! I know...But my employee wants a two y-axis plot so..:) But is there a solution with latticeExtra or not, do you know? Best regards

Comment: Using lattice,Extra I don't know, but the other answer using grid looks useful

Comment: Yes, thanks! Thanks for the answer again, I also did tell the employee that ggplot is better, but...Have a nice evening!